# pass parameter in a script.sh with function shell()

Tags: r, windows

I want to use shell commands under windows with R. So I use the shell () function by calling the bash program.

I create a script.sh which takes a word as parameter and displays it with echo, and it don't work, he returns the word "nothing", it does not take into account what I put in parameter.

**script.R**

```
pathShell <- "C:/Users/user/cmder/vendor/git-for-windows/bin/bash.exe"
cmd <- paste0("script.sh", " -a ", "something")

shell(cmd = cmd, shell = pathShell)
```

**script.sh**

```
val="nothing"

while getopts 'a:' opt; do
case $opt in
    a) val=$OPTARG    ;;

esac
done

echo $val
```

---

**version**

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.0                         
year           2019                        
month          04                          
day            26                          
svn rev        76424                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
nickname       Planting of a Tree
```

[R Documentation shell](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.0/topics/shell)

Comment: Where is `shell` from? Usually people use `system` or `system2` for this

Comment: Hello, I edited my post for added informations. I followed what documentation said. **Part Note**: *This function exists only on Windows: on all other platform system uses a shell.*